# How to search for ANYTHING in Chrome 22's Web Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome automatically updated on me to 22.0.1229.79, and right off the bat, there's no search functionality anymore!
[image: no search for you!]

Usually the search (whether it be for elements, "sources", etc.) is in the top-right.  But now I can't find it anywhere, and there doesn't seem to be an option to enable it.  Anybody figure  out where it is?

(It's on OSX, if that helps)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To search the currently highlighted script:
Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

To search all sources:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer.

Comment: Gotta wait 2 days!  I'll remember :)

Comment: Command-option-f searches across all scripts, as well.

Comment: Wow, bonus!  It even supports regular expressions!  Would be nice if it had the option to ignore whitespace, though.  People do have different spacing conventions.

Comment: Searching after a pretty print works though, and would help those that are diligent about typin' pretty

Comment: Chrome team, it would be nice if you add a search icon or button as well. I'm so used to CTRL+F triggering the browser page find that I didn't think to try it in the console.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+F` for non-mac keyboards